# Recovering Detoured Library Functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86, inline-assembly, detours

The question is fairly straight forward, what I'm trying to do is restore my process' detoured functions.

When I say detoured I mean the usual `jmp` instruction to an unknown location.

For example, when the ntdll.dll export `NtOpenProcess()` is not detoured, the first 5 bytes of the instruction of the function are along the lines of `mov eax, *`.

(The * offset depending on the OS version.)

When it gets detoured, that `mov eax, *` turns into a `jmp.`

What I'm trying to do is restore their bytes to what they were originally before any memory modifications.

My idea was to try and read the information I need from the disk, not from memory, however I do not know how to do that as I'm just a beginner.

Any help or explanation is greatly welcomed, if I did not explain my problem correctly please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out.

Example on NtOpenProcess.
Instead of restoring the bytes I decided to jump over them instead.

First we have to define the base of ntdll.

```
/* locate ntdll */
#define NTDLL _GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll")
```

Once we've done that, we're good to go. GetOffsetFromRva will calculate the offset of the file based on the address and module header passed to it.

```
DWORD GetOffsetFromRva(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * nth, DWORD RVA)
{
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(nth);

    for (unsigned i = 0, sections = nth->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i < sections; i++, sectionHeader++)
    {
        if (sectionHeader->VirtualAddress <= RVA)
        {
            if ((sectionHeader->VirtualAddress + sectionHeader->Misc.VirtualSize) > RVA)
            {
                RVA -= sectionHeader->VirtualAddress;
                RVA += sectionHeader->PointerToRawData;
                return RVA;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We call this to get us the file offset that we need in order to find the original bytes of the function.

```
DWORD GetExportPhysicalAddress(HMODULE hmModule, char* szExportName)
{
    if (!hmModule)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD)hmModule;

    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* pHeaderDOS = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *)hmModule;
    if (pHeaderDOS->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * pHeaderNT = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *)(dwModuleBaseAddress + pHeaderDOS->e_lfanew);
    if (pHeaderNT->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    /* get the export virtual address through a custom GetProcAddress function. */
    void* pExportRVA = GetProcedureAddress(hmModule, szExportName);

    if (pExportRVA)
    {
        /* convert the VA to RVA... */
        DWORD dwExportRVA = (DWORD)pExportRVA - dwModuleBaseAddress;

        /* get the file offset and return */
        return GetOffsetFromRva(pHeaderNT, dwExportRVA);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using the function that gets us the file offset, we can now read the original export bytes.

```
size_t ReadExportFunctionBytes(HMODULE hmModule, char* szExportName, BYTE* lpBuffer, size_t t_Count)
{
    /* get the offset */
    DWORD dwFileOffset = GetExportPhysicalAddress(hmModule, szExportName);
    if (!dwFileOffset)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    /* get the path of the targetted module */
    char szModuleFilePath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameA(hmModule, szModuleFilePath, MAX_PATH);
    if (strnull(szModuleFilePath))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    /* try to open the file off the disk */
    FILE *fModule = fopen(szModuleFilePath, "rb");
    if (!fModule)
    {
        /* we couldn't open the file */
        return 0;
    }

    /* go to the offset and read it */
    fseek(fModule, dwFileOffset, SEEK_SET);
    size_t t_Read = 0;

    if ((t_Read = fread(lpBuffer, t_Count, 1, fModule)) == 0)
    {
        /* we didn't read anything */
        return 0;
    }

    /* close file and return */
    fclose(fModule);

    return t_Read;
}
```

And we can retrieve the syscall index from the mov instruction originally placed in the first 5 bytes of the export on x86.

```
DWORD GetSyscallIndex(char* szFunctionName)
{
    BYTE buffer[5];
    ReadExportFunctionBytes(NTDLL, szFunctionName, buffer, 5);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return BytesToDword(buffer + 1);
}
```

Get the NtOpenProcess address and add 5 to trampoline over it.

```
DWORD _ptrNtOpenProcess = (DWORD) GetProcAddress(NTDLL, "NtOpenProcess") + 5;
DWORD _oNtOpenProcess = GetSyscallIndex("NtOpenProcess");
```

The recovered/reconstructed NtOpenProcess.

```
__declspec(naked) NTSTATUS NTAPI _NtOpenProcess
(
    _Out_    PHANDLE            ProcessHandle,
    _In_     ACCESS_MASK        DesiredAccess,
    _In_     POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    _In_opt_ PCLIENT_ID         ClientId
) {
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, [_oNtOpenProcess]
        jmp    dword ptr ds : [_ptrNtOpenProcess]
    }
}
```

Let's call it.

```
int main()
{
    printf("NtOpenProcess %x index: %x\n", _ptrNtOpenProcess, _oNtOpenProcess);

    uint32_t pId = 0;
    do 
    {
        pId = GetProcessByName("notepad.exe");
        Sleep(200);

    } while (pId == 0);

    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa;
    CLIENT_ID cid;
    cid.UniqueProcess = (HANDLE)pId;
    cid.UniqueThread = 0;
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&oa, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    HANDLE hProcess;
    NTSTATUS ntStat;

    ntStat = _NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, &oa, &cid);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(ntStat))
    {
        printf("Couldn't open the process. NTSTATUS: %d", ntStat);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Successfully opened the process.");

    /* clean up. */
    NtClose(hProcess);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the function ReadExportFunctionBytes, there is a resource leakage: need to call fclose(fModule) before the second last return.